# NGINX - Blog (index page) within site gets redirected through proxy correctly, but all sub-sites do not have the same redirect

Tags: php, django, wordpress, nginx

NGINX noob here, so please pardon my ignorance; I have a server running a DJANGO site, and WordPress blog in a Docker container within the same server; This is the way I have currently set up my NGINX configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 123.45.67.89;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/johndoe/djangosite;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/johndoe/djangosite/djangosite.sock;
    }

     location /blog {

        rewrite ^/blog(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8001";
    }
}
```

So using this NGINX configuration, accessing my server `123.45.67.89`, successfully brings up my Django site, and I'm able to use it to its full extent; accessing `123.45.67.89/blog`, takes me to my WordPress blog page (the blog index); at this point, clicking anything more within the WordPress blog (like a blog post, or the WP Admin site, or anything else related to the WordPress blog), will change the URL to: `123.45.67.89:8001/wp-login.php` instead of `123.45.67.89/blog/wp-login.php`.

How can NGINX be configured to use the blog url path, for everything related to the WordPress sub-site, and not just the WordPress index page? I want the port 8001, that keeps showing up in all WordPress URLs to be instead replaced with "/blog/", like it currently does on the blog index page? Is that at all possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: rearrege location. `location /` should be at bottom

Comment: thanks @itzMEonTV, but rearranging the `location /`, and moving it to the bottom, didn't have any real effect; did I misunderstand?

Comment: It will have. Did you tested?

Comment: Yes @itzMEonTV; just re-tested it; this is what the Nginx config file look like now:
`server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 123.45.67.89;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/johndoe/djangosite;
    }

    location /blog {

        rewrite ^/blog(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8001";
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/johndoe/djangosite/djangosite.sock;
    }
}`

Comment: and when trying to access the pages under the Wordpress blog, the URL becomes this: 

`http://123.45.67.89:8001/index.php/2017/07/03/hello-world/`

Comment: Dont know exactly what you are trying. What is the indention of rewrite in `/blog`.?

Comment: I may have gone about this the wrong way, with Nginx, but my goal is to access my WordPress blog (via `123.45.67.89/blog`), which is running in a Docker container on the host server, on the internal IP address: port, `127.0.0.1:8001`. And I need to access the rest of my Django site via the server root `123.45.67.89:80` on port 80. How is this doable using Nginx?

Comment: I feel, In your wordpress blog, you need to prepend "/blog" in every url.